# C++ - Creating a Low Pass Filter Function of Array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am supposed to take an array of integers, and a window size and "smooth the values of the array out. Meaning, it does this by taking the average of x values before and x values after a particular number and replacing that number with that average in a new array. Example, input array of {3,4,1,4,3,7,8} with a window size of 3. First and last values would be 0 as the window cannot extend before/after the array.

Here's my code

```
int *lowPassFilter(int arr[], int windowsize) {

    // initialize new array to be returned
    int *newarray[(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))];

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[0]) {
            newarray[0] == 0;
        } else if (arr[i] == arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])]) {
            newarray[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])] == 0;
        } else if (((arr[i] - windowsize) < windowsize) || ((arr[i] + windowsize) - sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])) < windowsize) {
            newarray[i] == 0;
        } else {
            newarray[i] == ((arr[i - ((windowsize - 1) / 2)] + (arr[i - ((windowsize - 1) / 2) + 1])
            + arr[i] + (arr[i + ((windowsize - 1) / 2)]) + (arr[i + ((windowsize - 1) / 2) + 1])) / 2);
        }
    }
    return newarray;
}

int main() {
    int g = rand() % ((7 - 3) + 1) + 3
    int test[] = rand()
    lowPassFilter(test, g);
}
```

The window size must be a value between 3 and 7, and the inputted array must be randomly generated.

I'm really stuck as how to fix this function. What I have does not compile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At least format your code properly.

Comment: Write down the expected output of given input example. After reviewing your code, I think you stuck with very basic C/C++ issues, such as _array declaration_, _array initialization_, _memory allocation_, and _function_. I suggest you to read array related tutorial like http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: If this is your actual code, the body of main is curiously malformed

Comment: If the code does not compile, compiler should produce some kind of error message. Please add it to your question. Although you could just read it and google it at first.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<int>`. This code has major issues due to its use of C arrays. That said, I don't see what those if-statements are trying to achieve. I think you should try the exercise on paper first, manually.

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from multiple serious flaws. I think you're misunderstanding basic types like arrays etc. Just start with,

- Your code is missing a `#include <cstdlib>`, causing the compiler not to find a definition for function `rand()`. In C++ it might actually be good style to call it as `std::rand()` instead.
- Statements in your `main` function are not followed by semicolons.
- `sizeof(arr)` will return `sizeof(int *)` instead of the size of the array passed, because a function parameter with the type `int[]` basically decays to a pointer to `int`. Hence, inside the function, the size of array `arr` is not known, the function only has a pointer. I suggest the entire array be passed as an `std::array` instead, or using a `int *` to point to the data and a `std::size_t` to hold the size.
- `return newarray;` attempts to return a value of type `int **` whereas the function type specifies the return type as `int *`. Either way, you're returning a pointer to some local data, therefore ever accessing it after the function returns is undefined behavior. You specified the type of `newarray` incorrectly as an array of pointers to `int` whereas you probably wanted an array of `int` instead.
- `int test[] = rand();` attempts to initialize an `int` array with an `int` scalar.
- You use `something == somethingElse;` have no effect, where you probably meant to use `something = somethingElse;`.
- The index `int i` of the `for`-loop is signed variable, but you compare it with an unsigned `(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))`. This might also lead to an undefined behavior (probably infinite loop) if `i` overflows before ever reaching `(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))`. There is also at least one other signed-vs-unsigned comparison in the code. I suggest that variables holding sizes of arrays and other objects be of the unsigned type `std::size_t`.
- Note that array indexes start from `0` (and not from `1`). Hence `newarray[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])]` attempts to access an out-of-bounds array element, one past the end of the array.

You're code would also be more readable if you formatted it a bit, and de-duplicated some code. For example you could write

```
newarray[i] == ((arr[i - ((windowsize - 1) / 2)] + (arr[i - ((windowsize - 1) / 2) + 1])
+ arr[i] + (arr[i + ((windowsize - 1) / 2)]) + (arr[i + ((windowsize - 1) / 2) + 1])) / 2);
```

more understandably as

```
auto const j = (windowsize - 1) / 2;
newarray[i] = (arr[i - j] + (arr[i - j + 1]) + arr[i]
               + (arr[i + j]) + (arr[i + j + 1])) / 2;
```

Next time, if something doesn't work and you want StackOverflow users to help you, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Protip: Always compile your code with compiler warnings enabled, and read the warnings and suggestions. With GCC and Clang you should use the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` compiler flags.